# UIAHost Request example with json

Tags: javascript, ios, rest, request, ios-ui-automation

has someone any ideas, how can i make a request with UI Automation and JS with UIAHost. An example is welcome with POST as method, some data and json as datatyp.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make an HTTP request via UIAutomation would be to [make a cURL request via the shell](https://superuser.com/a/149335) using [performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAHost/performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout).

If you are making a POST request with a lot of data, you may want the shell command to read the data from disk (instead of specifying it all on the command line).  Our Illuminator project provides [a function that lets you write arbitrarily large files to disk from within UIAutomation](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/ab757f0da3059d75c40a427b788d8fd471564efa/gem/resources/js/Extensions.js#L1650-L1712).